# How to use RewriteRule like WordPress and Drupal

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a website with an include script that will have a various number of variables.

Here are some of the types of URLs and variables:

`Main page: index.php

Login page: login.php (redirects to index.php after login).

Logout page: logout.php (redirects to login after logout).

Profile page: index.php?id=profile

Users password page: index.php?id=profile&sub=password`

And some pages even has more variables in the URL. I want to use RewriteRules to be able to get nice URLs like this:

`url.com/my/site/ (base)

url.com/my/site/profile/ (profile page)

url.com/my/site/profile/password/ (password page)

url.com/my/site/profile/password/variable1/variable2/variable3/ (use variables in the URL)`

How can I do this in the .htaccess-file? The site is not the root on the domain, but a couple of folders down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` rules apply to its container directory and all of its sub directories. This might be a good starting point:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Removing .php file extension.
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

Or you might want to remove the index.php's GET parameters from within url:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Removing GET parameters.  
    RewriteRule ^index/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

## Read more:

- [5 Useful URL Rewriting Examples Using .htaccess](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)
- [URL Rewriting Via .htaccess](http://web-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/url_rewriting_via_htaccess)
- [mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/)
- and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=.htaccess%20mod_rewrite%20nice%20urls&btnG=Search&cts=1238931487633&aq=f&oq=)