# How to rewrite user profile page?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, permalinks

In my page a user profile can be accessed for example by **domain.com/profile.php?id=1** or **name=admin**

My question is how to rewrite this and can be successfuly accessed by **domain.com/admin** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use RewriteRule like WordPress and Drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718695/how-to-use-rewriterule-like-wordpress-and-drupal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+) profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I will make use of id only,not the name. How does this change for every requested id?

Comment: @Nikolai: you'll request domain.com/admin and you want to deploy id instead of name? You have to do it inside your script

Comment: What I request is what I have to deploy? Ok with that. So how to do it for every name?